# Как обнулить global переменные python asyncio?

Tags: python, asyncio, aiohttp

Пишу личного Telegram Bot'a для сбора статистики по своим аккаунтам *market.csgo.com*. Основая задача бота - отправлять асинхронно запросы к API и выводить информацию через Telegram. Все работает как надо, но проблема с глобальными переменными, а точнее в их не правильном подсчете. Пример одной из моих функций:

```
...
import asyncio
import aiohttp


sale_total_sum = 0
amount_total_items = 0

async def get_on_sale(session, dictt, message):
    global sale_total_sum
    global amount_total_items

    async with session.get(f'https://market.csgo.com/api/v2/items?key={dictt[1][1]}') as resp:
        html = await resp.json()
        
        if html['items'] is None:
            pass
        else:
            each_sale_sum = 0
            each_amount_items = 0
            
            for i in html['items']:
                sale_total_sum += i['price']
                each_sale_sum += i['price']
                each_amount_items += 1
                amount_total_items += 1
               
            try:
                await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,
                    f'<a href="{dictt[1][0]}">{dictt[0]}</a> : <b>{each_sale_sum} ₽</b>\nItems: <i>{each_amount_items}</i>',
                    disable_web_page_preview=True, parse_mode=types.ParseMode.HTML)
            except exceptions.RetryAfter as e:
                await asyncio.sleep(e.timeout)


@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
async def Main(message):
    profiles = users()
    
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(trust_env=True) as session:
        tasks = []
        
        if message.text == 'On Sale ':
            await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Information request. Wait..')
           
            for i in profiles.items():
                task = asyncio.ensure_future(get_on_sale(session, i, message))
                tasks.append(task)
            await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
            
            await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,
                f'<b>Total on sale: {sale_total_sum} ₽\nTotal items: {amount_total_items}\nBot start at: {start}</b>',
                reply_markup=kb_client, parse_mode=types.ParseMode.HTML)


executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Результат функции:

```
Account_1: 100 ₽
Items: 1
Account_2: 200 ₽
Items: 2
Account_3: 300 ₽
Items: 3
Total on sale: 600 ₽
Total items: 6
```

Бот работает в режиме polling `executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)`. Если первый раз после включения вызвать функцию `async def get_on_sale`, то её конечный подсчет `Total on sale: 600 ₽ Total items: 6` будет верный, но последующие вызовы будут удваивать эту сумму, что на самом деле не так:

```
Account_1: 100 ₽
Items: 1
Account_2: 200 ₽
Items: 2
Account_3: 300 ₽
Items: 3
Total on sale: 1200 ₽
Total items: 12
```

Я знаю, что проблема в глобальных переменных `global sale_total_sum` и `global amount_total_items`. Но если вместо них использовать простые переменные, то они будут просто перезаписываться, а не суммировать как мне нужно. Поэтому хочу спросить - **есть ли способ как-то обнулить или переназначить эти глобальные переменные на 0 после завершения функции?** Что бы на следующем вызове данные были верны. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас время жизни этих данных должно быть пока выполняются все функции `get_on_sale` в рамках одного вызова `Main`.

Создайте объект с двумя полями и передайте его параметром в `get_on_sale`, чтоб многочисленные вызовы этой функции изменяли его. Когда все вызовы закончатся используйте результат:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class AggregatedStats:
    sum: int = 0
    items: int = 0

async def get_on_sale(session, dictt, message, stats):

      ...            
            for i in html['items']:
                stats.sum += i['price']
                each_sale_sum += i['price']
                each_amount_items += 1
                stats.items += 1
               
      ...

@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
async def Main(message):
    profiles = users()
    
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(trust_env=True) as session:
        tasks = []
        
        if message.text == 'On Sale ':
            await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Information request. Wait..')
           
            stats = AggregatedStats()

            for i in profiles.items():
                task = asyncio.ensure_future(get_on_sale(session, i, message, stats))
                tasks.append(task)
            await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
            
            await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,
                f'<b>Total on sale: {stats.sum} ₽\nTotal items: {stats.items}\nBot start at: {start}</b>',
                reply_markup=kb_client, parse_mode=types.ParseMode.HTML)
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, теперь все работает как надо!